# How can I read file on the iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, file

I can write file in path:

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

but I can't read this file.
What I must do?

Regards

Comment: Are you surprised you can't open a directory?

Comment: I can open directory and I can write file, but reading failed - no data in rcv buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The code you listed above just gives you a path of the document directory.

You need to provide a specific file... such as:

```
if([dirPaths count] > 0)
{
    NSString * documentsDirectory = [dirPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
    if(documentsDirectory)
    {
        NSString * docPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/TheFileIAmLookingFor.txt",       
          [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}
```

and then try something like:

```
NSString * contentsOfDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: docPath]
```

to get the actual contents of the file.

Comment: I can write any file with own name on this path (docPath), but i can't read it. On simulator I can change Mac folder permissions, and read operations are OK. But what I must do in physical device?

Comment: My answer hopefully gives you some good clues.  You're attempting to read a directory, not a specific file. Learn how to read from a file on the iPhone and you'll have a happier time.

Comment: If I write file (this is in my question) - the path and the filename are OK. My question is about different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a file with a name to a directory.
When you want to read that file back, you have to tell the OS which file you want to read.

Below is code which enumerates the files in a directory, in this example, the "Documents" directory.

At some point, the code must make a decision about WHICH FILE TO READ.

```
NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:  @"Documents"];
NSFileManager *localFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum =
    [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];


NSString *file;
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
            if ( [file isEqualToString: _The_NAME_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR_] ) {
            NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir,file];
                // READ YOUR FILE FROM HERE
            NSDictionary *attrs = [localFileManager 
                       attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
            if ( error ) {
               NSLog(@" error - %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@" file : %@", file);
                NSInteger fsiz = [attrs fileSize];
                NSString *ftyp = [attrs fileType];
                NSDate   *fmod = [attrs fileModificationDate];
                            NSInteger fperm= [attrs filePosixPermissions];
                NSLog(@"  %9d : %@ : %@ : %@ : %d",  fsiz, file, ftyp, fmod, fperm );
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I can write file on full path ".../Documents/sdtest.txt". This file exist, i see it in Organizer "Data files in Sanbox". But when I read it, in the same path with the same filename ".../Documents/sdtest.txt" - no return data in the rcv buffer. In iPhone simulator this is no problem, I can change folder permissions to "read&write". But I don't know, what I must do in device.

Comment: I added some code to the answer above that dumps out the attributes of all files in the directory, including size and permissions.  Make sure your file actually has a non-zero size.